# Working with NSUserPreference

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to make a simple app on the iphone.

I use simple UILabel that I have set on a NSTimer to change a phrase every 24 hours

When the app is closed or suspended I need to know how to use the NSUserPreference to store the data and time for the next phrase to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you don't mean [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: Possibly would that have control over that type of command that im looking for?

Comment: Read the documentation u'll find by clicking the link, and u should know.

Comment: I can't find what im looking for within the NSUserDefaults. Im looking for either the default setting or preference to basically keep my app timing going when it is off or suspended to keep the phrase changing every 24 hours.

Comment: I would just put a NSDate object into the userdefaults, each time ur phrase was updated. if the app is switch on or unsuspeded, check if the time went more than 24 hours further. I use the same method for periodically checking some informations on a server.

Comment: i fixed the link (wasnt too hard with the search mask)

Answer (score 0):

I believe vikingosegundo is correct regarding meaning NSUserDefaults.

Here is a [link to a video tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/), watch.. review the code and then you will learn it as opposed to someone just pasting some code in here for you.